# Deployed war file not starting in tomcat manager

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, broadleaf-commerce

i'm using tomcat v6.0. i have deployed admin.war from the manager page. and when i check the webapps directory i can see it is been extracted too..but i can't start that site from the tomcat manager..
This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID">

<display-name>mycompany-admin</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>blAdmin.root</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>patchConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:/bl-open-admin-contentClient-applicationContext.xml
        classpath:/bl-open-admin-contentCreator-applicationContext.xml
        classpath:/bl-admin-applicationContext.xml
        classpath:/bl-cms-contentClient-applicationContext.xml
        classpath:/bl-cms-contentCreator-applicationContext.xml
        classpath:/applicationContext.xml
        classpath:/applicationContext-email.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-datasource.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-admin-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-admin-filter.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-admin.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>shutdownHookMethod</param-name>
    <param-value>forceFlush</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
         org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- enable configured logging -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Initialize spring mvc -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/applicationContext-servlet-open-admin.xml
            classpath:/applicationContext-servlet-admin.xml
            classpath:/applicationContext-servlet-cms-contentClient.xml
            classpath:/applicationContext-servlet-cms-contentCreator.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-servlet-admin.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- specify the url pattern that will engage spring mvc -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>appName</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>admin2</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

Comment: Is there any errors shown in tomcat cmd??

Comment: You should check the logs for errors. For Linux normally under $CATALINA_HOME/logs

Comment: @jijeshAj:yeah i checked the error log...it says this..INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor admin.xml
Nov 14, 2014 11:35:38 AM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException: ${database.driver}
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:699)
"catalina.2014-11-14.log" 3807L, 333538C

Comment: @KaterinaA.: i'm getting the error "FAIL - Application at context path /mycompany could not be started" in the tomcat manager..

Comment: You are missing the JDBC drivers for MySQL. Download them from MySQL's website and add the driver to your classpath, to your project, or to Tomcat's $CATALINA_HOME/lib directory.

Comment: Check your database configuration file.

Comment: @jijeshAj:you mean the server.xml file in tomcat config directory..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that broadleaf has some properties into `context.xml` for site and admin, and wrapped inside war. You have to change those properties according to your connection details.

Here is the big hint

```
14, 2014 11:35:38 AM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference java.sql.SQLException: ${database.driver}
```

note that `${database.driver}`, if you'll search inside your project you'll see that there is `/src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml`

This post might help you, [How to run broadleaf on Tomcat instead of jettyserver..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989211/how-to-run-broadleaf-on-tomcat-instead-of-jettyserver/27178280)

Answer (score 0):

```
Driver :-  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Url    :-  jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.232:3306/entrance
```

Comment: Thanks..! in which all files should i add this.?

Comment: Your answer appeared in the low quality review queue. Please add a proper description to your "solution".

Answer (score 0):

First copy the JDBC Driver's jar into $CATALINA_HOME/lib.

Then add something like the following in the tomcat server.xml file

```
<Resource name="jdbc/YourDB"
  global="jdbc/YourDB"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YourUser"
  username="Yourusername"
  password="Yourpassword"
  maxActive="100"
  maxIdle="20"
  minIdle="5"
  maxWait="10000"/>
```

Then add the following in the server context.xml file

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/YourLocalDB"
            global="jdbc/YourDB"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

There is a detailed tutorial here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#MySQL_DBCP_Example