# How to run broadleaf on Tomcat instead of jettyserver..?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jdbc, broadleaf-commerce

I followed all the instructions that was provided in broadleafcommerce's documentation. I could run the site on jettyserver before making changes to the Mysql integration. but after i Followed the Mysql integration instructions that were given in the "getting started" page, it stopped working on jettyserver as well...what may be the problem..?

[http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/tutorials/getting-started-tutorials/switch-to-mysql-tutorial]

Therefore i tried to run the website on the tomcat 7.0 server...but saw the following errors while running catalina.sh

```
Nov 18, 2014 12:27:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: ${database.driver}
Nov 18, 2014 12:27:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Nov 18, 2014 12:27:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/mycompany] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 18, 2014 12:27:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /Users/mac/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/mycompany.war has finished in 2,617 ms
Nov 18, 2014 12:27:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Users/mac/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/docs
Nov 18, 2014 12:27:29 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester fatalError
SEVERE: Parse Fatal Error at line 29 column 6: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
SEVERE: Occurred at line 29 column 6
Nov 18, 2014 12:27:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
Nov 18, 2014 12:27:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Nov 18, 2014 12:27:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

this is my context.xml of tomcat/config:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0


-->
<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
<Context>

   <Resource auth="Container" 
       name="local_jdbc_db"  
       type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
       driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  
       url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/broadleaf" 
       username="root" 
       password="admin123"      /> 
   </Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
     on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->

</Context>
```

and my server.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />

  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->


    <Resource name="jdbc/broadleaf"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    username="root"
    password="admin123"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    description="Global Address Database"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mycompany"
    maxActive="15"
    maxIdle="3"/>
 </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">


    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->



    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
     This connector uses the BIO implementation that requires the JSSE
     style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
     OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
     documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />




    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
      /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
      /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
       via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
         resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
         that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
         available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone.! i changed my mysql default port number and config. it was running on port 8080 which is the default port of apache tomcat.so i changed mysql port number to 3306.Now  the program run smoothly!!

Answer (score 0):

Your context.xml has an extraneous `</Context>` element right above `<WatchedResource>`. Remove that and I'll bet it will work.

Comment: :Thanks philip, i corrected it but that doesnt seem like the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using broadleaf 3.1.x GA or 3.0.x GA and you want to use mysql and external tomcat
you need to add this dependency into `/pom.xml` (base pom) :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.21</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

and into `site/pom.xml` and `admin/pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

also you need to change following files for each resource:

`/site/src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml` and `/admin/src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml`

```
...
      username="${database.user}"
      password="${database.password}"
      driverClassName="${database.driver}"
      url="${database.url}"
...
```

you could have

```
...
      username="root"
      password="your-password"
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306"
...
```

this should work.